# Position button to the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to position button_pair to the bottom of the screen. I have tried wrapping everything in a LinearLayout and implementing the same Space component as below but it still doesn't position the button to the bottom of the screen. Is there a way for me to position to the bottom of the screen and set my margins according to the bottom? TIA.

```
<Space
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/user_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/main"
                app:civ_border_width="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edittext_email"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/button_logout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/user_name"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="14dp"
                        android:layout_height="14dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/online_status" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/online"
                        android:textColor="#808080"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <Space
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_logout"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:backgroundTint="#00000000"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                app:icon="@drawable/logout_24px"
                app:iconGravity="textStart"
                app:iconPadding="0dp"
                app:iconSize="34dp"
                app:iconTint="@color/black"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/search"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edittext_email"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_info" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_email"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
            android:hint="@string/searchY"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/edittext_email"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_title"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,VisualLintTextFieldSize" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/y_image"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/main"
            app:civ_border_width="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/y_info"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edittext_email" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/y_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_pair"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/y_image">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/y_name"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textview_email"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/y_email"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textview_name"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_pair"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/main"
            android:elevation="15dp"
            android:text="@string/pair"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:icon="@drawable/add_comment_24px"
            app:iconGravity="textEnd"
            app:iconPadding="8dp"
            app:iconTint="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/y_info"
            tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Why have you added a `NestedScrollView` as root view ? Can your layout extend beyond the screen size? I think you want your whole layout to appear on the screen at a time? Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using a `ScrollView`, which won't let you put items at bottom because they are scrollable, you will have to dock the button at bottom by moving it out of ScrollView. However, it seems like you don't need a scroll view since all your layout fits on the screen. So, I have given an implementation below without the scroll view.

**Tip:** Since you are already using a `ConstraintLayout` you don't need all those extra Linear layouts, it will help to load your screen faster. You can achieve any complex layout just using with the Constraint layout and proper constrains.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/main"
        app:civ_border_width="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_profile"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button_logout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/online_icon"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_online"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/user_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/online_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Online"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/online_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_name"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_logout"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#00000000"
        app:icon="@drawable/icon_logout"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:iconSize="34dp"
        app:iconTint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edittext_email"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profile_image" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_search"
        android:hint="Search here"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_title"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,VisualLintTextFieldSize" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/y_image"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/main"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_profile"
        app:civ_border_width="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edittext_email" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textview_email"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/y_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_pair"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        android:text="Pair"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:icon="@drawable/icon_pair"
        app:iconGravity="textEnd"
        app:iconPadding="8dp"
        app:iconTint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Sample Output:

[image: Sample Output]